# semantic zoom grouped data binding and accessing individual items

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm binding data to my ZoomedOut semantic zoom as so:

```
var result = from title in _allTitles group title by title._titleSubject into grp orderby     grp.Key select grp;
groupedTitlesSource.Source = result;
(semanticZoom.ZoomedOutView as ListViewBase).ItemsSource = groupedTitlesSource.View.CollectionGroups;
```

And am accessing the Key using Group.Key but I also want to access the first item in the group, what's the easiest way of doing this?  My Xaml is below for the ZoomedOutView:

```
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                <GridView x:Name="zoomedOutGridView" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="210" Height="140" Background="#CC196CFF">
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding Group.Key}"
                                    FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                                    FontSize="24"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                                <!-- Also want to access the first item in the group here -->
                            </Grid>    
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
```

Any help would be great, and I'm very new to this so simple as possible :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first place your Group.Key should be in the GridView.GroupStyle and your items should be under GridView.ItemTemplate. With that you will be able to access to the group items itself.